# VS 2010 Default unit test attributes for mvc controller is reason test fails to run, but why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, attributes

I created a default MVC 4.0 Internet web app in Visual Studio 2010. On one of the auto-gen'd home controller methods, I right-clicked and created a unit test. I choose a separate/new project. The test code looks like:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Index
    ///</summary>
    // TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page (for example,
    // http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to be executed on the web server,
    // whether you are testing a page, web service, or a WCF service.
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("E:\\Backup 20080915\\Projects\\Writing Projects\\Blogs\\31a\\QUnitMVC\\jQueryMvcWebApp\\jQueryMvcWebApp", "/")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:61524/")]
    public void IndexTest()
    {
        HomeController target = new HomeController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        ActionResult expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        ActionResult actual;
        actual = target.Index();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

If I run the test, written entirely by VS, it fails with:

```
Failed  IndexTest   jQueryMvcWebApp.Test.HomeControllerTest.IndexTest   The Web request 'http://localhost:61524/' completed successfully without running the test. This can occur when configuring the Web application for testing fails (an ASP.NET server error occurs when processing the request), or when no ASP.NET page is executed (the URL may point to an HTML page, a Web service, or a directory listing). Running tests in ASP.NET requires the URL to resolve to an ASP.NET page and for the page to execute properly up to the Load event. The response from the request is stored in the file 'WebRequestResponse_IndexTest.html' with the test results; typically this file can be opened with a Web browser to view its contents.
```

If I comment out the following 3 attributes, the test runs as expected:

```
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("E:\\Backup 20080915\\Projects\\Writing Projects\\Blogs\\31a\\QUnitMVC\\jQueryMvcWebApp\\jQueryMvcWebApp", "/")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:61524/")]
```

So my question is, why are they default settings, and when should I keep them uncommented?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message carefully, you'll see why.  You're not actually loading an ASP.NET page that can successfully get to the Load event.  You're running MVC, which really doesn't have "pages".  I fully unit test every one of my controllers/actions and I have never attempted using those attributes. May be something in Visual Studio test to default those attributes for any .net web app - when really it should just be for web forms apps.